# How to delete files on iMac with no menus -- Your startup disk is full

Tags: imac, memory, disk-space

I have an iMac with the 10.4 OSX operating system installed.  When I boot the computer it prompts me with this message:  "Your startup disk is full.  You need to make more space available on your disk by deleting files".  I am able to login and see the desktop background, but I cannot see any menus.

How can I delete files or erase all the data?  I have the startup disks but when I hold down C as the disks instructions say, nothing when I reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting files in single user mode:

- Restart
- Hold ⌘S after hearing the startup sound (it doesn't work if I start holding it before the computer has restarted)
- Run `mount -uw /` (`fsck -fy` is not needed)
- Run something like `rm -r /Users/username/.Trash/`
- `reboot`

Comment: It's prompting me for "override rw-rw-rw 501/staff for /foldername/filename/here.extension"  I've pressed "Y" and enter on each file but after reboot, I'm still out of space.  I ran the command again, but all of the same files get prompted again for this questions.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm also trying: rm -rf /Users/username/.Trash/
But it's coming back with the "Read-only file system" comment on each file

Comment: It worked for me (on 10.8). The `-w` option of `mount -uw /` should mount the filesystem as writable.

Comment: Somehow I missed the trailing "/" on the mount -uw command.  Thanks, that worked!